# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

I am running into below error with the below piece of code,can any one provide suggestions on how to fix it?

```
import json
gerritinfo=['{"project":"platform/frameworks/opt/telephony","branch":"kitkat","id":"Idcf6faee0f6259704ea07b62ce713ebdd4c5da1b","number":"739919","subject":"Correct order of parameter in iccExchangeApdu()","owner":{"name":"Satish Kumar Singh","email":"c_ssing@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"c_ssing"},"url":"https://review-android.quicinc.com/739919","createdOn":1399412660,"lastUpdated":1399437231,"sortKey":"002cea91000b4a4f","open":true,"status":"NEW","comments":[{"timestamp":1399412661,"reviewer":{"name":"Gator Service Account","email":"gator@localhost","username":"gator"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\\n\\nThis patchset has been processed by the Gator."},{"timestamp":1399412704,"reviewer":{"name":"Checkpatch Service Account","email":"checkpatch@localhost","username":"checkpatch"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\\n\\nYour change has passed all of the checks enforced by the android patchchecker."},{"timestamp":1399413456,"reviewer":{"name":"Satish Kumar Singh","email":"c_ssing@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"c_ssing"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399415354,"reviewer":{"name":"Gueyoung Lee","email":"gueyoung@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"gueyoung"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399417092,"reviewer":{"name":"Dhananjai Singh","email":"dhananja@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"dhananja"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399417366,"reviewer":{"name":"David Ng","email":"dng@quicinc.com","username":"dng"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, approved\\n\\nI remembered the previous change went in recently.  How come this was not caught in the original testing as this would have failed right away?\\n\\nThanks!\\nDavid"},{"timestamp":1399418880,"reviewer":{"name":"Klocwork Automation User","email":"kwuser@localhost","username":"kwuser"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nThis change is being verified in klocwork for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217513\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,\\n\\n\\n\\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\\n\\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\\n"},{"timestamp":1399418898,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nThis change is being verified in lookahead for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217515\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\\n\\n\\n\\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\\n\\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\\n"},{"timestamp":1399418924,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nThis change is being verified in lookahead for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217517\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\\n\\n\\n\\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\\n\\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\\n"},{"timestamp":1399422861,"reviewer":{"name":"Klocwork Automation User","email":"kwuser@localhost","username":"kwuser"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Verified\\n\\nSuccessful klocwork verification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217513\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399427087,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Verified\\n\\nSuccessful lookahead verification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217515\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399427807,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nSuccessful lookahead verification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217517\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399428952,"reviewer":{"name":"PATCHSET LOCK CNSS GERRIT","email":"cgpl@localhost","username":"cgpl"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Patch Set Locked\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399433104,"reviewer":{"name":"Preflight Locking User","email":"preflight@localhost","username":"preflight"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\\n\\nLocked for preflight"},{"timestamp":1399433250,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nThis change is being verified for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219556\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735646\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733482\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734797\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738976\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,740118\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728537\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728778\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728784\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729018\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729147\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731124\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731160\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731551\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733219\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734250\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734472\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734487\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734503\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734923\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735244\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735559\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,736352\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/mdm/manifest:master:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219555\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,740118\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:master_64:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219557\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735646\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733482\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734797\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738976\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,740118\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n\\n\\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\\n\\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\\n"},{"timestamp":1399434561,"reviewer":{"name":"Preflight Locking User","email":"preflight@localhost","username":"preflight"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Not developer verified\\n\\nUnlocked"},{"timestamp":1399434591,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\n\\nAborted verification due to sibling job failure as part of parallelverification. This change will get picked up in subsequent verification cycles. No action is needed.\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399435613,"reviewer":{"name":"Preflight Locking User","email":"preflight@localhost","username":"preflight"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\\n\\nLocked for preflight"},{"timestamp":1399435770,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\nThis change is being verified for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219789\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,737413\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,716076\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,737755\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739365\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,703116\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728537\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728778\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,728784\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729018\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729147\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731124\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731160\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,731551\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733219\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734250\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734472\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734487\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734503\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734923\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735244\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735559\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,736352\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733482\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734797\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735646\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738976\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,740134\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734263\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/mdm/manifest:master:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219788\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,716076\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,737755\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,703116\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:master_64:default.xml\\n\\n\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\u003d\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3219790\\n\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,716076\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,737755\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739365\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,703116\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,733482\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,734797\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,735646\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738976\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,740134\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,707889\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717048\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717049\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,717050\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,725038\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,729385\\n\\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,738249\\n\\n\\n\\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\\n\\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\\n"},{"timestamp":1399436746,"reviewer":{"name":"Preflight Locking User","email":"preflight@localhost","username":"preflight"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Not developer verified\\n\\nUnlocked"},{"timestamp":1399436759,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\\n\\n\\nAborted verification due to sibling job failure as part of parallelverification. This change will get picked up in subsequent verification cycles. No action is needed.\\n\\n"},{"timestamp":1399437231,"reviewer":{"name":"Preflight Locking User","email":"preflight@localhost","username":"preflight"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\\n\\nLocked for preflight"}]}\n', '{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":4}\n']
dict_data =json.loads(str(''.join([item.replace('\n', '') for item in gerritinfo])))
for c in dict_data['comments']:
    if c['reviewer']['name'].startswith('Klocwork'): # you can use exact search
        print c['message']

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    dict_data =json.loads(str(''.join([item.replace('\n', '') for item in gerritinfo])))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 26242 - line 1 column 26295 (char 26242 - 26295)
```

Comment: As it says, you are trying to `replace` on a list, which doesn't support that.  Why do you have `[]` around `gerritinfo` instead of just `gerritinfo = '{"project"...'`?

Comment: Actually, if you scroll to the far right, you'll see that he actually has (at least) two elements in the list.

Comment: @BrenBarn/jon - TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: On order to fix this code we need to know what is that input data and what your code is trying to do.

Comment: @warwaruk - input is already given in the script..if that works,i can fix my code

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Oops, didn't notice that gap in the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of `\n`s in your list, the following code would do it.

```
gerritinfo = [
    '{"project":... ... Locked for preflight"}]}\n',
    '{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":4}\n'
]
print ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in gerritinfo])
```

**UPDATE**

The following code may work. If I didn't misunderstand your question.

```
import json
# gerritinfo = [....]
dict_data =json.loads(gerritinfo[0])
for c in dict_data['comments']:
    if c['reviewer']['name'].startswith('Klocwork'): # you can use exact search
        print c['message']
```

*output:*

> Patch Set 1:
>
> This change is being verified in klocwork for the following manifests
>   along with other changes as detailed below:
>
> =====================================================================================
>
> git-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml
>
> =====================================================================================
>
> https://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513
>
> ---
>
> o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,
>
> Please note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be
>   successful before this change can be merged.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE
>   VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.
>
> Patch Set 1: Verified
>
> Successful klocwork verification. You may find the results of the
>   verification by following the link(s) below:
>
> https://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513

Comment: i want to print latest message for reviewer which starts with klockwork

Comment: @python.beginner what does `klockwork` mean? and I'm not familiar with `gerrit` so is it possible to abstract the question to a `python` question?

Comment: i updated the main question with the latest code and error..it has the input,please check if the code you posted works for the input shared

Comment: @python.beginner I seems like you only care about messages by `Klocwork Automation User`, just pass `gerritinfo[0]` into `json.loads()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: this is much better but a small bug,the latest message from Klocwork Automation user is .....Klocwork Automation User  5:34 PM

Patch Set 1: Verified

Successful klocwork verification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:

https://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513 .... we should print this

Comment: @python.beginner That's because the `message` is `Patch Set 1: Verified\\n\\nSuccessful klocwork verification. You may find the results of the verification by following the link(s) below:\\n\\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\\u003d3217513\\n\\n` If you want to format the output, that would be another question.

Comment: i think i dont get you...how is my request related to formatting the output?the output is itself is not correct...need to print the latest message from Klockwork Automation User

Comment: @python.beginner your example code just prints whatever message is in the json file by the `Klockwork xxxx` user. And my answer correctly prints that out.

Answer (score 3):

replace method only for string, not a list . so we mention the position of particular list value

```
dict_data =gerritinfo[0].replace('\n','')
```

if you want  total list value in dict_data means that you can use for loop

```
a=[item.replace('\n', '') for item in gerritinfo]
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylst = map(lambda each:each.strip("\n"), gerritinfo)  
print mylst
```

This works for lists. You're essentially deleting the character from the elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Because `gerritinfo` is a list, you have to access `.replace()` with each string in the list. Here is a method using list comprehension:

```
import json
gerritinfo=['{"project":... ... Locked for preflight"}]}\n', '{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":4}\n']

dict_data =json.loads(str(''.join([item.replace('\n', '') for item in gerritinfo])))
for c in dict_data['comments']:
    if c['reviewer']['name'].startswith('Klocwork'): # you can use exact search
        print c['message']
```

Using list comprehension, we loop over each item in `gerritinfo` and we call the `.replace()` on it.

Here is a little example of using list comprehension:

```
>>> squares = range(1, 11)
>>> squares
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> squares = [x**2 for x in squares]
>>> squares
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>>
```

Comment: `json.loads` needs a string as its input, so add `str` around the list

Comment: @aj8uppal - did your code work for you?it is compilation errors.....  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    dict_data =json.loads([item.replace('\n', '') for item in gerritinfo])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffe

Comment: @aj8uppal - i updated the main question with the current error